# my DNF repo (Fedora37) no longer functions. I think I need to reinstall/repair it. Can I reinstall a fresh Fedora dnf repository?

Tags: linux, fedora, repository, dnf

Yesterday, I upgraded my Fedora35 to Fedora37.  Prior to the upgrade, it informed me that python2.7 (which is intentionally still on my Linux machine) would be removed.  I hesitated at that (we still have product in the field running old versions, so we have to maintain support for Python2.7).

I decided to upgrade anyway, then reinstall Python2.7.  I did all of that successfully (I thought).  I recreated symlinks to use both Python3.8 + Python2.7 (I also have Python3.11).  I could launch either Python shell successfully.  From what I can remember from yesterday (I've slept since then), my first clue that something was wrong, was when I went to do a simple "dnf list" and Fedora said it could not find this file:  "libpython3.10.so.1.0".  THAT was totally unexpected as I do not even have Python3.10 installed (so why is it looking for that).

I cannot now remember the steps I took after that, as I have looked online and tried several things since.  Which brings me to where I am at now.  When I try to do ANYTHING with the dnf command (or yum), I get an error message like this:
dnf clean expire-cache

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 61, in 
from dnf.cli import main
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dnf/**init**.py", line 30, in 
import dnf.base
. . . .
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dnf/yum/rpmtrans.py", line 26, in 
import rpm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpm'

I looked for the rpm.py in the "/usr/lib/" + "/usr/lib64/" directories.  I see the "rpm.py" file here:
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sos/policies/package_managers/rpm.py
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sos/report/plugins/rpm.py
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sos/policies/package_managers/rpm.py
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sos/report/plugins/rpm.py

Since the Python traceback indicates a failed import in the "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dnf/yum/rpmtrans.py" I have copied the "rpm.py" file above into a couple of other Python3.8 directories in hopes that it could be found (and thus imported) when required by the dnf repo.  I have manually copied the "rpm.py" file here:
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dnf/rpm/rpm.py
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dnf/yum/rpm.py

BUT, I cannot seem to resolve this problem.  I have searched online for reinstalling a fresh dnf/yum repository, but most of the hits discuss reinstalling packages (Not the whole repo).  I think I need a whole new dnf/yum repo, as I would like to start from scratch with a brand new dnf/yum repo and then go thru and do package installs for the various packages I need.

I would prefer to not have to reinstall the entire O/S, if I do not have to.

Thank you for reading this far, and thank you in advance, for any assistance.

Comment: I'm guessing the extra python installs overwrote or misconfigured the system enough so that `dnf` no longer works. If `rpm` still works (e.g., `rpm -qi dnf`), you could play the `dnf` role by (re-)installing all the packages you need from koji.  For example, you could determine the dependencies of `dnf` (and dependencies of dependencies, etc.) and install (or partially reinstall) the RPMs directly (`rpm` has lots of options).  This process wouldn't be fun and I hope you have backups of all you important data, etc.

Comment: Many thanks @rickhg12hs for reading my long post and adding your insight.  I hesitate to go down the path of known pain (as you described), so it looks like the path of least resistance for me, is to reinstall the O/S from scratch.  That will, yes, wipe out all configurations and all package installs which I will have to re-establish.  The command you mentioned (e.g.  "rpm -qi dnf") does work, at least it returns a summary of the dnf/yum repo with version information.  If you could, what is your reference to "koji" about?  I am not familiar with "koji".

Comment: But I also wonder if, as you mentioned, my intentional installation of Python2.7 was in fact the culprit to disable my dnf/yum repo (or at least disable it somewhat), then what is the chance that after reinstalling the O/S from scratch (which comes with Python3.x by default), and then reinstalling Python2.7 (because we have to support legacy systems in the field), that I will end up at the same spot?  Grrrr.

Comment: _"Koji is an RPM-based build system. The Fedora Project uses Koji for their build system ..."_ "koji" is also a Fedora website with all the Fedora RPMs for at least all the supported Fedora releases (and probably some that have EOL'ed, I didn't look).  For example, https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=2061075 has links/downloads of interest for the latest `dnf` package for Fedora 37.  You can explore the website to get a sense of what's available.

Comment: You need to make sure that any installs don't corrupt the installed Fedora packages, either by overwriting/deleting important files or changing important configurations.  I usually put my "add-ons" in `/usr/local`, `/usr/local/src`, or `/opt` (if I have write permission there), or even in some directory tree under my home directory if it's just for me.

Comment: Many thanks @rickhg12hs